# Velocity and acceleration of a ball shot uphill

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics, acceleration, velocity

Consider a ramp of length $100$ m and with a height of $10$ m. At the base of that ramp we're shooting a ball of mass $12$ kg uphill. Let's say the ball has a speed of $1$ m/s at $1$ m uphill. How can I calculate the velocity and acceleration the ball has after $2$ m, $3$ m, etc.? How far will that ball rise before it will roll backward? Consider that there's no friction at all.

I found tons of explanations on how to calculate the downhill move of a ball, but never an example of how to do it the other way around.

Comment: Shooting with 100N uphill cannot be useful. If you have a finite force over essentially zero time, then the ball will not be going upwards at all. Do you mean to continuously pull with the same force, or do you mean a different unit? And what direction exactly? And the past tense of shoot is shot.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent: My fault, you're of course correct. I changed the question and assumed that the ball has a given speed at 1 m uphill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the ball is rolling upward freely, there is no force along its upward path so drawing a simple force diagram we find that:
$$-mg\sin{\alpha} = ma \rightarrow -g\sin\alpha = a$$

Where we assume the angle at the ramp's base is $\alpha$

Note that the mass is irrelevant as expected, all masses respond the same to the influence of gravity, and the ball is only influenced by gravity here.

Now using the kinematic formula for the displacement of a body undergoing constant acceleration:

$$x=x_0+\left(\frac{v+v_0}{2}\right)t$$

We put $x_0=0$, $v=1$ and $x=1$ to find the $t$ for which as assumed we obtain this speed at this given position:

$$1=\left(\frac{1+v_0}{2}\right)t$$
$$t=\frac{2}{1+v_0}$$

Putting this into $v=v_0+at$ with $v=1$ and the constant acceleration $a$ we found before, we obtain the ball's initial velocity:

$$1=v_0-g\sin\alpha \frac{2}{1+v_0}$$
$$v_0 = \sqrt{1+2g\sin\alpha}$$

So the required expression for the speed wrt time is

$$v=\sqrt{1+2g\sin\alpha}-g\sin\alpha \cdot t$$

And we can see that the ball will reach $0$ speed when:

$$\sqrt{1+2g\sin\alpha}=g\sin\alpha \cdot t_{halt}$$
$$t_{halt}=\frac{\sqrt{1+2g\sin\alpha}}{g\sin\alpha}$$

Accordingly, the displacement with respect to time is

$$x=\sqrt{1+2g\sin\alpha}\cdot t-g\sin\alpha \frac{t^2}{2}$$

Plugging in our $t_{halt}$, we find the largest displacement it obtains:

\begin{aligned}
x_{max}&=\frac{1+2g\sin\alpha}{g\sin\alpha}-g\sin\alpha \frac{1+2g\sin\alpha}{2g^2\sin^2\alpha} \\
&=\frac{1+2g\sin\alpha}{g\sin\alpha}-\frac{1+2g\sin\alpha}{2g\sin\alpha} \\ &= \frac{1+2g\sin\alpha}{2g\sin\alpha}
\end{aligned}

Comment: I'm already stuck with the mass ... If I'd roll another ball, I'd expect to see that it should make a higher distance, shouldn't it? Moreover, a ball with a bigger mass should encompass a higher inertia. Shouldn't this impact the acceleration of the ball along the ramp?!

Comment: No. I think you're confused by the following: since by assumption you have the ball having a speed of $1m/s$ after $1m$ of ascent, it indeed means that for a more massive ball, the momentum with which it begins its ascent at the bottom of the ramp needs to be indeed, larger for a more massive ball. Momentum classically is $mv$, so proportional to $m$ as you can see. How it obtained this initial momentum $mv$ is not a part of the problem as you presented it.

Comment: Oh, wow. Thanks a lot. Now I got it. Thanks for your explanations!